# Dynamic Character Count

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I am using Datatables, to Dynamically add Rows to my Table, 
I have 3 columns,

1. Index
2. Text
3. CharCount

I need logic for implementing a **character count of every 'Text' column in it's respective 'CharCount' field**,

Here's my Code -

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var t = $('#example').DataTable();
    var counter = 1;

    $('#addRow').on( 'click', function () {
        t.row.add( [
            counter,
            '<input type="text" id=textBox'+counter+'/>',
            '<input type="text" id=counterBox'+counter+' disabled="true"/>'
        ] ).draw( false );

        counter++;
    });

    // Automatically add a first row of data
    $('#addRow').click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

<button id="addRow">Add</button>    
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Index</th>
            <th>Text</th>
            <th>CharCount</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Index</th>
            <th>Text</th>
            <th>CharCount</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

So for example, a user types something in the Text column,
 using an on keyUp event, I'll need the total count of characters typed,
 to be displayed in the respective CharCount column's textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery [.map()](https://api.jquery.com/map/) to go throu all the fields.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
            var t = $('#example').DataTable();
            var counter = 1;
            $('#addRow').on( 'click', function () {
                t.row.add( [
                    counter,
                    '<input type="text" id="textBox'+counter+'" />',
                    '<input type="text" id="counterBox'+counter+'" readonly />'
                ] ).draw( false );

                counter++;
            } );
  
           $(document).on( 'keyup', 'input[id^=textBox]', function () {
                $(this).parents('tr').find('input[id^=counterBox]').val($(this).val().length); 
            } );

            // Automatically add a first row of data
            $('#addRow').click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"> 
    <button id="addRow">Add</button> 
    <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Index</th>
                <th>Text</th>
                <th>CharsLeft</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Index</th>
                <th>Text</th>
                <th>CharsLeft</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

Comment: Not really what I  wanted, I need the CharsLeft to display the number of characters in the Text column, something like on keyUp event of Text column, the respective CharsLeft column will display the total number of characters typed in the Text column.